# ASP.NET MailMessage.BodyEncoding and MailMessage.SubjectEncoding defaults

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

Simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere on MSDN...

Looking for the defaults ASP.NET will use for:

`MailMessage.BodyEncoding` and `MailMessage.SubjectEncoding`

If you don't set them in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [`MailMessage.BodyEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding.aspx) MSDN says:

> The value specified for the
>   `BodyEncoding` property sets the
>   character set field in the
>   Content-Type header. The default
>   character set is `"us-ascii"`.

For `MailMessage.SubjectEncoding` I was also unable to find any documented default value, but reflector is to rescue:

```
internal void set_Subject(string value)
{
    if ((value != null) && MailBnfHelper.HasCROrLF(value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("MailSubjectInvalidFormat"));
    }
    this.subject = value;
    if (((this.subject != null) && (this.subjectEncoding == null)) && 
         !MimeBasePart.IsAscii(this.subject, false))
    {
        this.subjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    }
}
```

`MimeBasePart.IsAscii` is an internal method which tries to determine whether the passed value is in `ASCII` encoding:

```
internal static bool IsAscii(string value, bool permitCROrLF)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    foreach (char ch in value)
    {
        if (ch > '\x007f')
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!permitCROrLF && ((ch == '\r') || (ch == '\n')))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So it seems the default encoding for subject will be `UTF-8` in the most cases.

Comment: Aghhh! It must be documented, I couldn't understand why if US-ASCII is the default encoding, it was sending correctly accents and other special characters. The source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs,8a4fd36de4145dc5,references